# How many solutions does $2^z=1$ has, where z is a non-zero complex number.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $z=x+i y$

Then $2^z=2^{x+i y}=1$

Now how to proceed further? Is it correct to take $\log_2$ on both sides? Does the RHS, then become zero?

Comment: I would personallly use $a^z = e^{z\ln(a)}$ and proceed from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write $2$ as $e^{\ln 2}$, so that $2^z = e^{z\ln 2}$. Then $2^z = 1 \Rightarrow e^{z\ln 2} = 1$. Does that help?

As $z = x + iy$, $e^{z\ln 2} = e^{x\ln 2 + iy\ln2} = e^{x\ln 2}[\cos (y\ln) 2 + i\sin (y\ln 2)]$, by using Euler's formula $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$.

Therefore, $e^{x\ln 2}[\cos (y\ln) 2 + i\sin (y\ln 2)] = 1$. As the imaginary part must be $0$, we have $\sin(y\ln 2) = 0 \Rightarrow y\ln 2 = n\pi \Rightarrow y = n\dfrac{\pi}{\ln2}$, and $\cos(y\ln 2) = \cos n\pi = (-1)^n$.

Thus, $(-1)^n e^{x\ln 2} = 1 \Rightarrow x = 0$ and $n$ is even.

So, $z = \dfrac{2k\pi i}{\ln 2}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So $e^{x ln 2}=1$ (that is the argument) and $e^{i(y ln 2)}=1$

Comment: @SwapnilTri That's right.